# defining a variable in JS with { } around variable name - what is this called?

Tags: javascript

I upgraded a npm and now my webpack fails around this line here.

```
const { theme } = params;
```

What does this mean when you have { } around the variable name?

Comment: [Destructuring assignment - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Comment: Destructuring assignement :) ES6 feature

Comment: This is supported in standard ecmascript?

Comment: @jremi Click Andreas' link and look at the compatibility table.

Comment: Check [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility) @jremi

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

This is called destructuring assignment. The [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.